# power on vmware(vCloud) instance on demand

Tags: java, vmware, vcloud-director-rest-api

We have several private vCloud vmware instances on which are deployed some java webaps. The instances are not corelated with each other.

I am monitoring the usage of the apps and have some instances that are not used for days or even months.

Is there a way maybe already built in vmware to stop the instance when not used for some days and to restart it fast when a new request comes in.

The motivation for this is just to optimize wmware licence costs.

I am already monitorng the requests to some instance and I know I could do ti thrugh vCloud Java api but I dont know if it would be fast enough to start the instance when a new request comes.

Ahy hints in which direction should I go?